# Decent Visual SQL query Builder

Tags: sql, oracle, helper

I am a code developer, not a DBA, and I tend to get lost with loooong SQL queries, when I use many joins (10 joins is pretty common for me).

I would like to find a Visual SQL Query Builder (free if possible) that could connect to Oracle and see all the tables there, so I would only select visually my keys that link the Joins, and select the fields I want to be shown.

Comment: You're a coder who needs visual aids?

Comment: It's very possible he's never worked extensively with a declaritive, set-based language like SQL.  Some people learn visually.

Comment: @Emyr Developing and writing SQL Scripts are two different things :D.

Comment: I cannot unit test individual pieces of a SQL query, because, sometimes, the minimal SQL Select I need to return what I want is 200 lines long. I think visually some of this complexity will fade away.

Comment: @Emyr, when I have to create or debug huge queries, I draw a chart... i f I can have the tools to do it automatically I will be happy... and more productive too. What you said is like: who needs and IDE with refactoring tools...

Comment: My point was more about the aptitudes expected in someone who choses to be and describe themselves as a coder. If you find LINQ easier to use, you could try LINQPad (paid for, so you get Intellisense) so you can more easily wrangle your data, then let it generate the SQL for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-to-oracle#32467 for Linq-to-oracle...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle's own SQL Developer (free to download Java app) has a visual [query builder](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/images/what_query.png) (I haven't used it though, so this is not a recommendation, merely an FYI).

More about Oracle SQL Developer (and download link) [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not free, but I use pl sql developer

http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html

Answer (score 1):

use Visual Studio Server Explorer to connect to oracle and then build queries using query builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try **SQLeo Visual Query Builder**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqleo/

It permits to join tables visually

Answer (score 1):

Try [Insight Developer for Oracle](http://www.tncas.com), but note that it is not free. I use it on both Mac and Linux.