# any free linq provider available for oracle?

Tags: asp.net, linq, silverlight, odp.net

I am looking for a free linq provider for oracle. I dont need advanced features. What all I need is CRUD operations + ability to generate model from oracle db.

I would like to use this on production web site(using ASP.NET & Silverlight).

Any pointers & suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out a few things:

### LinqToOracle at CodePlex

http://linqtooracle.codeplex.com/

Supposedly there is some .NET 4.0 beta related activity going on. [Update: "Supposedly" looks to actually have meant "Not at all."]

### Another similar SO question

[Is there a Way to use Linq to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-to-oracle)

A bit dated, but a decent place to start.

### DevArt's dotConnect for Oracle

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

They've got a free trial.  Was previously known as OraDirect.

Personally, I've kinda given up on this myself, content to wait for support in the Oracle data provider from Oracle.

[Update]

### Oracle's ODP.NET

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/oracle-entity-framework-sod-130214.pdf

Oracle's own data provider will support it in 2011, with a beta available near the end of 2010.  Better late than never, eh?

Comment: Try Express edition of Devart LinqConnect - <a href="http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/linqconnectfree.exe">LinqConnect</a>. It is free.