# Using LINQ to SQL with Oracle

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

i know that linq to sql is really "LINQ to SQL Server". I also read that one can build his own LINQ Provider in order to connect to other database systems like oracle or mysql. my question is how to build a LINQ Provider and what are the advantages and disadvantages of using LINQ to SQL on databases other than SQL Server.

Comment: try looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-to-oracle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a good article which describes how to build a LINQ provider:

[Building a LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee672195.aspx)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 12):

LINQ to SQL doesn't support Oracle, but the Entity Framework has a more open provider model, and there are Oracle drivers which support EF.

So basically, for non-SQL Server databases I would ignore LINQ to SQL completely and look to EF. LINQ to SQL simply wasn't built with a provider model for extensibility to arbitrary databases.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this 
[LINQ to Oracle](http://linqtooracle.codeplex.com/)

But Linq to SQL not so good for ORM as Nhibernate, or Entity Framework. Nhibernate works with Oracle, MS SQL server, My SQL et. EF - works with MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

You can try 3-rd party ORMs - for example, [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/), NHibernate, etc. But as for me - LINQ to SQL is flexible and allows you to start quickly.