# How to use LinqToSQL on Oracle database?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

How to use Linq to SQL over an Oracle database or MySQL database, and still get the same functionality and performance as with using it with SQL server.

Comment: You have to go with Entity Framework instead. At least officially Linq to SQL works only with SQL Server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-to-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Read this [oracle](http://www.datadirect.com/resources/ado-net/oracle-console/index.html) and you can get same functionality (as standard LINQ) from this [linqtooracle](http://linqtooracle.codeplex.com/)