# LINQ Correlated SubQuery throws Oracle Exception: Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 does not support APPLY

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, linq

Here is the c# query:

```
qry = qry.Where(comment => idsArr.Any(
                           selectedId => dbv.VW_STAKEHOLDER_TYPE_XREF.Where(xref => xref.STAKE_ID == comment.STAKE_ID && xref.STAKEHOLDER_TYPE_ID == selectedId).FirstOrDefault() != null
                            ));
```

From the language of the exception I am guessing that something in the c# is being translated to an apply which Oracle 11 doesn't like for some reason. I am not sure which part of the query is getting translated into APPLY and how I can circumvent this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Entity Framework?

Comment: @Aron We are using entity framework in the app. What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL only really works with SQL Server, although some simple queries may work on other databases. In this case the query failed as Oracle does not have a `CROSS APPLY` clause, but uses lateral joins instead. See this post for options when you want to use LINQ with Oracle: [Is there a Way to use Linq to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-to-oracle)